# Meilisearch max retries exceeded

Tags: python, meilisearch

I'm developing an app in Streamlit, it used to work but now when I try to access I am receiving an error.

This is part of my code using meilisearch.

```
import requests

query = "Technology"

#params
params = dict(q=query)
headers = {'X-Meili-API-Key': KEY}

def get_regulation():
    lexai_url = "http://35.223.18.2/indexes/eurlex/search"
    result = requests.get(lexai_url, params=params, headers=headers).json()
    reg = []
    for i in result["hits"]:
        title = i["title"]
        author = i['author']
        date = pd.to_datetime(i['date']).date()
        link = i['link']
        reg.append({
            "title": title,
            "author": author,
            "date": date,
            "link": link
        })

    return reg

get_regulation()
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='35.223.18.2', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /indexes/eurlex/search?q=Technology (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10bd31310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out'))
```

Comment: Did  you set the port for MeiliSearch to 80? Typically it runs on port 7700 so if you didn't change it to 80 maybe that is the issue.

Comment: Thank you @paul41 for your help! I've try to change the port to 7700 and when I try to run the Streamlit app in localhost it's working, now the problem its when I deploy the app using Heroku, I have the same error but with the 7700: 

`ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=7700): Max retries exceeded with url: /indexes/twitter_press/search?q=Technology&filters=timestamp+%3E+1627032415.380851&limit=10000 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff2021e3fa0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))`

Comment: Your host of `127.0.0.1` is for local host so you will need to change the host to point to Heroku. I have not used Heroku before so I'm not sure, but you may also need to open port 7700 on the Heroku side (not sure if that is even possible).